# Cannot select Phoenix securecore BIOS values

Tags: bios

When entering my BIOS (Phoenix securecore) the only values I can select and change are System Date, System time, Set User password, and the exit settings (excluding reset default values).

I haven't had this problem before and need to change my boot priority order to boot from USB. How can I regain control of my BIOS again?

Comment: Sounds like maybe a password was added. It would help if you provided the make/model of your motherboard or computer.

Answer (score 0):

Figure out which motherboard you have, and follow the BIOS reset procedure.

Generally,

1. Unplug the computer
2. Change the BIOS reset jumper
3. Sometimes you have to take the coin battery out.
4. Change jumper back
5. Put battery back if you removed it
6. Turn PC on and go into the BIOS

Sometimes, there a simple button you just have to push.

It all depends on your motherboard.